# company changed domain on their farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have a customer where they changed the domain name after share point was installed, so they have DOMAIN1, and now they have DOMAIN2,  so SharePoint stopped working,

We have changed app pools users, windows services, but still SharePoint is not working.

What else do I need to check?

Answer (score 1):

Since SharePoint is heavily engaged with SQL Server, you need to get your new service accounts in your new domain to mirror the service accounts in the old domain.

Application pools, SharePoint services, Windows services, Service Applications and Web Application are also using the old domain accounts. Application pools and Windows services can be NETWORK service account, and you don't have to change.

Depending on level of customizations it can be faster to set up a new farm in the new domain and make a database migration instead.

Some help on the way: [SharePoint : Migrating SharePoint Server from one domain to another](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sushrao/2011/12/02/sharepoint-migrating-sharepoint-server-from-one-domain-to-another/)

Answer (score 1):

Single Server farm is easy as Benny mentioned in his reply but Multi server farm is pain.

Migrating SharePoint farm from one domain to another is not easy process. You have to build new Farm on new Domain then restore the SharePoint farm backup. You can Move the SQL Server to different domain without any issue.

There are hard coded references, so that is not supported(farm's domain migration)

Here are the steps which should be perform in order to complete the migration.

- Backup your current farm(sharepoint farm backup).
- Disjoin the existing servers from current domain.
- Join the servers(Including the SQL Server) to the new domain.
- Re-create a configuration database in the new SQL location.(means
  rebuild the farm)
- Restore the farm from farm's backup.
- Restore any customizations (Customized web.config for forms
  authentication may apply.)
- Run the Migrate User to move all users from old domain to new.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/20ab9c73-ab38-47d0-a791-8f9004fbe1a4/move-sharepoint-farm-servers-to-another-ad-domain

and this

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/80058115-1c56-458b-aed0-b7bee8c15346/migrating-sharepoint-farm-including-sql-to-a-new-domain?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious